# SVM CLASSIFIER (Response array must contain as many elements as the total number of samples)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, svm

I am working on fungus detection using SVM. I have no clue why I am getting this error during training of classifier.

error: (-209) Response array must contain as many
elements as the total number of samples in function cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses

```
Mat classes;//(PosSamples+NagSamples, 1, CV_32FC1); 
Mat trainingData;//(PosSample+NagSample, imgWidth*imgHeight,CV_32FC1 );

cv::Mat trainingImages;
vector<int> trainingLabels;

 for (int pimageNum = 0; pimageNum < 359; pimageNum++)
  {
// reading Positive Samples
        trainingImages.push_back(posImage);
        trainingLabels.push_back(1.0);
}
for (int nimageNum = 0; nimageNum < 171; nimageNum++)
  {
// reading Nagative Samples
        trainingImages.push_back(nagImage);
        trainingLabels.push_back(0.0);
}
 Mat(trainingImages).copyTo(trainingData);
    trainingData.convertTo(trainingData, CV_32FC1);
    Mat(trainingLabels).copyTo(classes);

 FileStorage fs0("D:\\classifier.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
    fs0 << "TrainingData" << trainingData;
    fs0 << "classes" << classes;
    fs0.release();

 CvSVMParams SVM_params;
    SVM_params.svm_type = CvSVM::C_SVC;
    SVM_params.kernel_type = CvSVM::LINEAR;
    SVM_params.degree = 0;
    SVM_params.gamma = 1;
    SVM_params.coef0 = 0;
    SVM_params.C = 1;
    SVM_params.nu = 0;
    SVM_params.p = 0;
    SVM_params.term_crit = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 1000, 0.01);
    //Train SVM
    CvSVM svmClassifier(SVM_TrainingData, SVM_Classes, Mat(), Mat(), SVM_params);
```

///////////////// image size is 50x50  /////////////////

```
In Classifier.yml file.
TrainingData: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 26500
   cols: 50
classes: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 530
   cols: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each row (not each image) is a sample. So you have 26500 rows of samples, and 530 classes. That is due the fact that your images are 50 in height: 50*530 = 26500.

Usually you compute some sort of feature on your images to use in the SVM. If you want to use your original images, you should do one:

1. linearize / resize your images, so that each image is 1x2500. You'll obtain 530 training data and 530 classes.
2. replicate your classes 50 times for each image. You'll obtain 26500 training and 26500 classes.

It's up to you to decide if your whole image is a feature (case 1), or each row of your image is a feature (case 2).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried case.2 and it works :)
I did like this but still not sure its a good approach or not.
for (int nimageNum = 0; nimageNum < 171; nimageNum++)
  {
// reading Nagative images
        trainingImages.push_back(nagImage);
      for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        trainingLabels.push_back(0.0);
}

I have one more question, How can I draw a boundary rect around the object detected by using SVM classifier ?

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulHaseeb well, SVM will classify your image, not detect an object. However, If you are classifying patches in an image and have only two classes, you can draw a mask where for each patch you put the classified label value. Then a combination of contours detection and boundingRect should give you the boundary of the object.

Comment: Thanks.. but how can I do this? could you please share some code or some algorithm. I am working on SVM first time and it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulHaseeb post **another** question where you explain **in detail** what you want to do, what you have done so far **(including code)**, and what is your expected result. Right now there aren't enough details to help you.

Comment: I have posted another question and also the sample image. please take a look on my new post. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600540/how-to-highlightdraw-boundingrect-circle-around-the-object-detected-by-using-s